# Hibernate DAO in Spring Application: the Session object is automatically never closed, why?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am quite new in Spring world and I have develop a simple DAO using Hibernate that execute CRUD operation on a table in the DB.

Reading here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_sessions.htm I can read that:

> The Session object is lightweight and designed to be instantiated each
>   time an interaction is needed with the database. The session objects
>   should not be kept open for a long time because they are not usually
>   thread safe and they should be created and destroyed them as needed.

Reading online I have understand that Spring automatically open and close the Session object connection respectively when a @Transactional method is call and when it is closed and I don't need to handle manually this thing as is do here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_examples.htm (opening the Session when I enter in a CRUD method and close it before exit from it)

My DAO seems work well (correctly perform all the defined CRUD operation on the DB) but seems that the Session is never closed. It is automatically opened when I enter in the first CRUD method called but seems that don't close it when exit from it

I have used the following architecture: I have an **interface** named **PersonDAO** in which I declare the CRUD method that I desire use on my table and then I implement this interface using a concrete class named **PersonDAOImpl2** that implements the declared method by Hibernate.

This is my **PersonDAOImpl2** class code:

```
package org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.entity.Person;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class PersonDAOImpl2 implements PersonDAO {

    // Factory per la creazione delle sessioni di Hibernate:

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        // Metodo Setter per l'iniezione della dipendenza della SessionFactory:

        public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
            System.out.println("Ho iniettato la SessionFactory: " + sessionFactory);

        }

        public String getConnectionStatus(){

            return " Aperta: " + sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().isOpen() + " Connessa: " + sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().isConnected();
        }


        /** CREATE CRUD Operation:
         * Aggiunge un nuovo record rappresentato nella tabella rappresentato
         * da un oggetto Person
         */
        @Transactional(readOnly = false)
        public Integer addPerson(Person p) {

            System.out.println("Inside addPerson()");
            System.out.println("Connessione aperta: " + sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().isOpen());
            System.out.println("E' connesa:" + sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().isConnected());

            Integer personID = personID = (Integer) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(p);

            return personID;

        }

        // READ CRUD Operation (legge un singolo record avente uno specifico id):
        @Transactional
        public Person getById(int id) {

            Person retrievedPerson = null;

            System.out.println("Inside getById()");

            System.out.println("Inside addPerson()");
            System.out.println("Connessione aperta: " + sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().isOpen());
            System.out.println("E' connesa:" + sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().isConnected());

            retrievedPerson = (Person) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Person.class, id);

            return retrievedPerson;

        }

        // READ CRUD Operation (recupera la lista di tutti i record nella tabella):
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Transactional
        public List<Person> getPersonsList() {

            System.out.println("Inside getPersonsList()");
            List<Person> personList = null;

            Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Person.class);
            personList = criteria.list();

            return personList;
        }

        // DELETE CRUD Operation (elimina un singolo record avente uno specifico id):
        @Transactional
        public void delete(int id) {
            System.out.println("Inside delete()");

            Person personToDelete = getById(id);
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(personToDelete);
        }

        // UPDATE CRUD OPERATION (aggiorna un determinato record rappresentato da un oggetto)
        @Transactional
        public void update(Person personToUpdate) {

            System.out.println("Inside update()");

            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(personToUpdate);
        }

}
```

As you can see I inject the dependency of the SessionFactory object that I use to create the Session objects for the interaction with the database, all the CRUD method and a method named **getConnectionStatus()** that only return the status of the connection (return if the connection still remain open and connected)

To test my DAO I have implement a **MainApp** class containing the main() method and in which I test all my CRUD operation, this one:

```
package org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.dao.PersonDAO;
import org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.entity.Person;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "Beans.xml");
        System.out.println("Contesto recuperato: " + context);

        Person persona1 = new Person();

        persona1.setFirstname("Pippo");
        persona1.setLastname("Blabla");

        System.out.println("Creato persona1: " + persona1);

        PersonDAO dao = (PersonDAO) context.getBean("personDAOImpl2");

        System.out.println("Creato dao object: " + dao);

        dao.addPerson(persona1);

        System.out.println("persona1 salvata nel database");
        System.out.println("persona1 ha id: " + persona1.getPid());

        System.out.println("Recupero l'oggetto Person avente id: "
                + persona1.getPid());

        Person personRetrieved = dao.getById(persona1.getPid());

        System.out.println("nome: " + personRetrieved.getFirstname());
        System.out.println("cognome: " + personRetrieved.getLastname());
        System.out.println("ID: " + personRetrieved.getPid());


        System.out.println("Aggiungo altri 2 record nella tabella: ");

        Person persona2 = new Person();
        Person persona3 = new Person();

        persona2.setFirstname("Mario");
        persona2.setLastname("Rossi");
        persona3.setFirstname("Paolino");
        persona3.setLastname("Paperino");

        dao.addPerson(persona2);
        dao.addPerson(persona3);

        List<Person> listaPersone = dao.getPersonsList();

        for (Iterator iterator = listaPersone.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Person persona = (Person) iterator.next();
            System.out.print("Nome: " + persona.getFirstname());
            System.out.print(" Cognome: " + persona.getLastname());
            System.out.println("  ID: " + persona.getPid());
        }


        System.out.println("Elimina il primo record dalla tabella");

        Person firstPerson = listaPersone.get(0);
        System.out.println("Persona da eliminare: " + firstPerson);

        dao.delete(firstPerson.getPid());

        listaPersone = dao.getPersonsList();

        for (Iterator iterator = listaPersone.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Person persona = (Person) iterator.next();
            System.out.print("Nome: " + persona.getFirstname());
            System.out.print(" Cognome: " + persona.getLastname());
            System.out.println("  ID: " + persona.getPid());
        }

        System.out.println("Aggiorna il primo record della tabella:");

        firstPerson = listaPersone.get(0);

        System.out.println("Persona da aggiornare: " + firstPerson);
        System.out.print("Nome: " + firstPerson.getFirstname());
        System.out.print(" Cognome: " + firstPerson.getLastname());
        System.out.println("  ID: " + firstPerson.getPid());

        System.out.println("CAMBIO DEI DATI:");

        firstPerson.setFirstname("Gatto");
        firstPerson.setLastname("Silvestro");

        System.out.println("Nuovi dati: " + firstPerson);
        System.out.print("Nome: " + firstPerson.getFirstname());
        System.out.print(" Cognome: " + firstPerson.getLastname());
        System.out.println("  ID: " + firstPerson.getPid());

        System.out.println("UPDATING !!!");

        dao.update(firstPerson);

        listaPersone = dao.getPersonsList();

        for (Iterator iterator = listaPersone.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Person persona = (Person) iterator.next();
            System.out.print("Nome: " + persona.getFirstname());
            System.out.print(" Cognome: " + persona.getLastname());
            System.out.println("  ID: " + persona.getPid());
        }

        System.out.println(dao.getConnectionStatus()); 

    }

}
```

This is my XML configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd        
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd ">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SpringTestDb" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="aprile12" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="2" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="5" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="personDAOImpl2" class="org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.dao.PersonDAOImpl2" >
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Register @Autowired annotation -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
</beans>
```

My DAO seems work well (correctly perform all the definied CRUD operation on the DB) but seemes that the Session is never closed. It is automatically opened when I enter in the first CRUD method called but seems that don't close it when exit from it (I have tested it using a call to **getConnectionStatus()** at the end of main() method) and I am confusing about it...

So I am asking you:

1) Why the Session is not automatically close? is it so bad as I have read in the first Hibernate article have the same Session that still remain open?

2) Using this architecture (the interface and it's implementation) how can automatically close the Session when exit from a CRUD method?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: I would think that "getCurrentSession()" get you a new session, from the [JavaDoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html), "This factory bean will by default expose a transaction-aware SessionFactory proxy, letting data access code work with the plain Hibernate SessionFactory and its getCurrentSession()". [Observer paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer%27s_paradox) anyone?

Comment: mmm I don't understand what you mean but I think that I solve by myself...I had annoted also the entire class using Transactional annotation...deleting the transactional annotation from the class and let it only on the method seems work well !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're calling your DAO's `getConnectionStatus()`, and it returns that the session is open.

That's quite normal, since this method is just like the other methods of your DAO: Spring intercepts the call to the method, opens a session, executes the method, and thus, inside the method, you get an open current session.

Note that although there is no @Transactional annotation on the method, it is transactional, since you also put a `@Transactional` annotation on the class itself, making all its methods transactional.

Comment: mmmm I know that you are so good in Spring but are you sure about it?
Deleting the transactional annotation from the class (and leaving it only on the methods) it I run the main I obtain an exception when the getConnectionStatus() method is executed because there is no session open...so I think, correct me if I'm wrong, that annoting the entire class using Transactional it would be that all method are cosidered annoted and so Spring intercept also getConnectionStatus(). Is it right or is it a stupid idea?

Comment: That's exactly what I said. Your method is transactional because you put a Transactional annotation on the class.

Comment: ok, tnx perfect...so next step: I will study the use services for the DAO...as you said me in the past ;-)